# Using Fiddler to send a POST request to WebApi

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing a simple WebApi program, using C#. (I know MVC fairly well, but I'm new to WebApi.) It contains a Vendors controller (VendorsController.cs), which contains a "getvendor" action as shown in the code sample below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/vendors")]
public class VendorsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("getvendor"), HttpPost]
    public TAPUser GetVendor([FromBody] string username)
    {
        Int32 userid = -1;

    ...
```

The routes are configured as follows:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional
);
```

I'm using Fiddler to test the program. First, I ran the above code without [FromBody] and used Fiddler to send a POST request with the username in the url like this:
    http://localhost:60060/api/vendors/getvendor?username=tapuser

This worked fine. tapuser was passed as the argument to GetVendor and the action returned the expected result.

Next, I added [FromBody] and put `username=tapuser` in the request body. This time, when I sent the request, `tapuser` did not get passed to the action. The argument to `GetVendor()` was `null`. I've tried variations on the request body such as `{ "username": "tapuser" }`, but it doesn't help. I've tried changing the route in various ways, too, such as changing `routeTemplate` to `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`. That hasn't helped either. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but I just don't see it.

Comment: Did you make sure you specified the content-type as application/json in the request header? Could you share your fiddler screen shot/code if still unresolved.

Comment: Side note: Raw view of request from Fiddler as text would be better than image

Comment: POST http://localhost:60060/api/vendors/getvendor HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Content-Type: application/json
    Host: localhost:60060
    Content-Length: 16

    username=tapuser

Comment: I just posted the raw view. Sorry about the lack of formatting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try putting your value directly into the request body. See this.
[image]

Comment: Now that I look back at this, I realize that you had the right answer. I just didn't pick up on it. So thanks for your response.

Comment: @drunk.. thnx for clearing it out that for any object based parameter we don't need to use [Frombody], but for simple one we do need. However to pass parameter as string we do need quotes (Tim) it not as you are understanding as might not need in case of int

Answer (score 1):

Now I did some debugging and was able to recreate the issue you were having.

I was eventually able to get the data to the action by doing the following:

First I created a class to act as container for the payload.

```
public class body {
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

and updated the action to match

```
[Route("getvendor"), HttpPost]
public TAPUser GetVendor([FromBody] body payload) {...}
```

Then using fiddler I composted the request to the endpoint to test.

```
POST  http://localhost:60060/api/vendors/getvendor HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:60060
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16

username=tapuser
```

When my break point was hit the body/payload was populated with the username as tapuser.

**UPDATE**

Now while the above worked, I wasn't entirely sure that it solved your problem so I did some googling and came across this

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Where that showed the following example using `[FromBody]`

> To force Web API to read a simple type from the request body, add the
>   [FromBody] attribute to the parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

> In this example, Web API will use a media-type formatter to read the
>   value of name from the request body. Here is an example client
>   request.

```
POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 7

"Alice"
```

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header
>   to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is
>   "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a
>   JSON object).
>
> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So
>   this will not work:

```
// Caution: Will not work!    
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

> The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a
>   non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

When I reverted my original changes and followed the example it worked as intended.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried all of these things. Nkosi - It seems like you tried exactly the same things I did and they worked for you, but not for me. So I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if I put 'tapuser' in the request body, using either single or double quotes, it works. The quotes seem to be the answer. If I put anything other than tapuser inside the quotes, the whole thing gets passed as the argument. For instance, '{username=tapuser}' will get passed as {username=tapuser}. Thanks everybody for your input.